# What is a Rotten Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Rotten Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Rotten Words™ | Not Rotten Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ANT | BEETLE |
| BARF | VOMIT |
| CLERK | TELLER |
| EBBS | FLOWS |
| ENVY | JEALOUSY |
| FLAP | FLUTTER |
| GNAT | FLY |
| GREEN | BLUE |
| NOWHERE | SOMEWHERE |
| NUN | PRIEST |
| PURELY | MIXED |
| REEF | OCEAN |
| ROOF | CEILING |
| VEX | TROUBLE |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Rotten Words™,Not Rotten Words™
ANT,BEETLE
BARF,VOMIT
CLERK,TELLER
EBBS,FLOWS
ENVY,JEALOUSY
FLAP,FLUTTER
GNAT,FLY
GREEN,BLUE
NOWHERE,SOMEWHERE
NUN,PRIEST
PURELY,MIXED
REEF,OCEAN
ROOF,CEILING
VEX,TROUBLE
```

Comment: does font/case matter?

Comment: @dperry Neither font nor case matters for this one. It's a lot more fun that my previous ones, in my opinion.

Comment: 86% of rotten words are shorter than their non-rotten counterparts!

Comment: @Michael That's because most Rotten Words are short. It's hard to find a long one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Rotten Words are words that...

> can be ROT13'd to produce a new word. (A is replaced with N B with O, etc.)
>  These produce: `NAG ONES PYREX ROOF RAIL SYNC TANG TERRA ABJURER AHA CHERYL ERRS EBBS IRK.`

Comment: Wouldn't rot13("n" orpbzr "a" naq O" orpbzr " b")?